# Limit of an undamped driven harmonic oscillator

Tags: limits

Could someone give me at least a hint to how even start to calculate this?
$$\lim_{\omega \rightarrow \omega_0}\frac{F_0.[\omega_0.sin(\omega.t)-\omega.sin(\omega_0.t)]}{\omega_0.m.(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)}$$
$F_0$ , $\omega_0$ and $m$ are constants. 
It is a limit of the equation of motion of an undamped driven harmonic oscillator.

Comment: It's the form $0/0$. Use l'Hospital.

Comment: But it says that the result is $\frac{F_0.t^3.\omega_0}{6.m}$ and i am not getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They make one more assumption, that $t$ is small. Or $\omega_0$ is small. Then expand the expressions for sine and cosine: $$\sin\omega_0t\approx\omega_0 t-\frac 16\omega_0^3t^3\\ \cos\omega_0 t\approx 1-\frac 12\omega_0^2t^2$$
From l'Hospital, you get the limit $$\frac{F_0}m\frac{\omega_0 t\cos\omega_0 t-\sin\omega_0 t}{2\omega_0^2}\approx\frac{F_0}m\frac{\omega_0t(1-\frac 12 \omega_0^2t^2)-(\omega_0t-\frac 16 \omega_0^3t^3)}{2\omega_0^2}=-\frac{F_0}m\frac{\omega_0t^3}{6}$$